# jQuery - How do I find the next sibling that does not have class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list that has an expanded class that is dynamically set. I'm having trouble finding the the next list item in relation to ONLY the visible elements. `.siblings(':visible')` and `.next(':visible')` do not seem to work when the selector is on `jQuery('.expanded')` presumably because it is looking for the next expanded class.

```
<ul id="list_1" class="list">
    <li class="gridImage" data-id="Christmas"></li> //not visible
    <li class="gridImage" data-id="Christmas"></li> //not visible
    <li class="gridImage expanded" data-id="Easter"></li>
    <li class="gridImage" data-id="Valentines"></li> //not visible
    <li class="gridImage" data-id="Easter"></li>
    <li class="gridImage" data-id="Miscellaneous"></li> //not visible
</ul>
```

Comment: What makes an `li` visible?

Comment: @slicedtoad the `li` is made visible/invisible by another list using `show()` and `hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another way:
http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/kqpbh3fv/

```
$('.expanded').nextAll(":visible").first()
```

[`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) is like next but it grabs all the following siblings that match the selector. First takes only the first.

Comment: nice answer, i was trying as well but you answered before ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
.nextUntil(':visible').last().next()
```

that is find all the siblings till the next visible one, then take the last one from the set(so its next sibling should be the visible one) then its next sibling.

Comment: This worked for the code that I showed above, but does not work when the expanded class and the visible/invisible items start to change.